# Video (from html tag, using Angular) has no sound in Firefox, and no image in Opera, but in Chrome works fine

Tags: html, angular, browser, html5-video, mp4

I have got stuck using a video tag in different browsers. In Chrome, this works perfect (video shows image and audio).

```
    <video  #myvideo [src]="urlvideo" height="300" style="width: 100%;" controls autobuffer autoplay playsinline webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline">
```

However, in Firefox it is not possible to hear the video (shows only image, controls show muted and disabled audio button). Also, in Opera it is not possible to view the video (can hear audio only, controls are visible).

Using source tag, adding or removing the optional attributes, it behaves the same way:

```
    <video height="300" style="width: 100%;" controls autobuffer autoplay playsinline webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = false">
      <source [src]="urlvideo" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

More info: Tried on Ubuntu and Windows, and the results are the same. Browsers DevTools does not show any incompatibility warning or error.

I guess I am missing something, do you know what could it be or have any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Download **MediaInfo** and check the audio/video codecs used. MP4 can have either VP9, H.264 or H.265 codecs. Not all browsers handle the codec. For cross browser compatibility make sure the MP4 has H.264 video and AAC audio.

Comment: Thank you @VC.One, I realized some test videos had OGG audio.  A video with AAC audio worked in Firefox. In Opera, I've got neither audio nor video.

Answer (score 0):

Though mp4 should work across all browser I advise you to check other version too. Use below code that need other variation of videos.

```
<video width="100%" height="300" controls="controls">
   <source src="media/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
   <source src="media/intro.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
   <source src="media/intro.webm" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```

Comment: Although it is also important, this comment does not answer the question, since I am using mp4 files for testing and browsers are recognizing them.